# Inserting values into multi-dimentional javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to dynamically create a multidimensional javascript array that matches this layout:

array_answers[0][1]:"yes"
array_answers[1][2]:"no"
array_answers[2][2-subquestion]:"text input"
array_answers[3][8]:"yes"
array_answers[4][8-subquestion]:"text input"

The first "[ ]" defines what question it is on the page (out of *totalInputs*)
The second "[ ]" defines what question from the database this is (*questions* already in order to match the corresponding input)
and the information following is the input I am trying to add

I have attempted to the following with no luck.

```
for(var i = 0; i < totalInputs; i++) {
  array_answers.push([i]);
  array_answers[i].push([questions[i]]);
  array_answers[i][0] = "yes, no, or other text";
}
```

The last line is where it falls apart. It would make sense to me that I should be able to use [0] to indicate that I want the first array to be given this value but with no avail.
I have also tried:

```
for(var i = 0; i < totalInputs; i++) {
  array_answers.push([i]);
  array_answers[i].push([questions[i]]);
  array_answers[i][questions[i]] = "yes, no, or other text";
}
```

but this gives me lots of empty arrays for all the numbers from 0 to whatever the value of questions[i] is.
What am I missing or is there a simpler way to do this in jQuery while still conforming to the target layout?

Comment: I don't understand the layout.

Comment: It would help if you showed what `array_answers` should look like if everything works.

Comment: That's a very confusing structure, with each `array_answer` being an array with nonstandard properties added to it, in addition to having numeric indicies. You'll probably find it a lot easier to think about if you make it into a full object instead.

Comment: For clarification array_answers should look like this:
array_answers = 
  [0][1]:"yes"
  [1][2]:"no"
  [2][2-subquestion]:"text input"
  [3][8]:"yes"
  [4][8-subquestion]:"text input"

The required layout is a mess I know, it has to be this way so I don't have to re-write the entire project I'm having to make changes to

Comment: In your example, you have `array_answers[3][8]:"yes"]` This suggests that `array_answers[3]` holds an array with 8 empty slots and a 'yes' in the ninth. That seems a little strange.

Comment: Maybe what you want is a 2-dimensional object and not a 2-dimensional array. Something like: `{ 0: { 1: ..., 2: ... }, 2: { "2-subquestion": ... }, 3: { 8: ... }, ... }`

Comment: I get the feeling you might need to improve your understanding of arrays and objects. If you can show an exact version of the result you want (with valid javascript), and possibly also any input you have to work with, we can step through the thought process with you.

Comment: So you want to transform something into something else. If you can clearly define both somethings, then someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to store questions and prompts (maybe?) together in a multi dimensional array. let me suggest a different way that should work.

```
const array_answers = questions.map(q => [q, "yes, no, other text"]);
```

This may be what you want

Answer (score 0):

I am still not 100% sure of what you need, but i thought I would write an answer with my assumptions, that I can update as the information improves.

> The first "[ ]" defines what question it is on the page (out of
>   totalInputs)

This part looks like you are correct, and need to use an array. But an array is just a list of "things", in your case, questions. So where you have this line:

```
array_answers.push([i]);
```

I'm not sure it is doing what you are expecting. This is adding a new array item, which is in itself an array, that contains a single number. So if `totalInputs` is 3, then that first line will result in this structure:

```
array_answers= [[0],[1],[2]]
```

I think what you actually might intend here is to simply house an array of question details. Now by the complexity of your keys listed for the second dimension, it looks like an object would be more appropriate.

> The second "[ ]" defines what question from the database this is
>   (questions already in order to match the corresponding input)

So lets go ahead and create a single question.

```
var question = {
  anythingYouWant: 'here',
  2: 'even numeric keys'
}
// you can access the values in these ways
console.log(question.anythingYouWant)
console.log(question[2])
console.log(question['anythingYouWant'])
```

Now once you have a question object, you can then add it to your `array_answers` array with push.

```
array_answers.push(question).
```

If you have two identical questions like the one above, your array will look like this:

```
array_answers = [{
  anythingYouWant: 'here',
  2: 'even numeric keys'
},{
  anythingYouWant: 'here',
  2: 'even numeric keys'
}]
```

In order to access the questions within the array, you can simply use their index:

```
// access second question
var secondQuestion = array_answers[1]
```

---

You can read these links to learn more about [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) & [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)